# Creating a new SQL Table with data from existing

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create and populate a new table from data within existing tables all within 1 procedure, but I keep getting an error about duplicate keys. This has to be done within 1 procedere file for it is for an assignment. I have already tried to use SELECT INTO to populate most_profitable but that did not work.

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Procedure (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the procedure.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Daniel McClure
-- Create date: 11/17/2014
-- Description: Calculates The Most Profitable Titles
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE MostProf   
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE dbo.most_profitable
(
pub_id char(4) NOT NULL,
profit money
PRIMARY KEY (pub_id)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.most_profitable
(
   titles.pub_id
)
SELECT
titles.pub_id 
FROM titles


END
GO
```

The error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__most_pro__2515F222534D60F1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.most_profitable'.

Answer (score 1):

What this most likely means is that the original table has duplicates, that is, **titles.pub_id** is currently not a unique list. That is, you're trying to make it unique, and it is not.

To confirm this, run this query:

```
SELECT titles.pub_id, COUNT(*) As CountForPub
FROM titles
GROUP BY titles.pub_id
ORDER BY CountForPub DESC
LIMIT 20
```

If you see any pub_id's that have the count greater than 1, you know that you have duplicates.

Comment: Thank you! All I had to do was throw in a DISTINCT to avoid multiples!